Cannot import module that is installed
I have installed a Python module in a virtual environment on Ubuntu, but it is not found (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neuroHarmonize'). I used pip install neuroHarmonize. When I activate my environment and run pip show neuroHarmonize I get:
Name: neuroHarmonize
Version: 2.4.1
Summary: Harmonization tools for multi-center neuroimaging studies.
Home-page: https://github.com/rpomponio/neuroHarmonize
Author: Raymond Pomponio
Author-email: raymond.pomponio@outlook.com
License: 
Location: /home/neuromod/ad_sz/scripts/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages

so it looks like it has installed correctly. I have tried everything here. Grateful for any guidance, thank you!

What if you do python -m pip show neuroHarmonize?

That gives me the same as above. It seems to be an issue with the library, installing an older version helped. Thank you!

According to their Github Repo the solution seems to be installing an older version (2.3 instead of 2.4).
Source: This Issue here.
